# Drawing a tree in JAVA with asterisks and tabs - can't include floor in the code

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, ascii

My code print a tree with a trunk size of 2 spaces in an array, in the last space it needs also a floor, but i don't know how to implement this, so far my code works like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //up part
  for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
  for(int k=1; k<=6-i+1; k++){
  System.out.print(" ");    
  }
  for(int j=1; j<=2*i-1; j++){
  System.out.print("*");    
  }
  System.out.println();
  }
  
  // trunk
  for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
  for(int k=1; k<=5; k++){
  System.out.print(" ");    
  }
  for(int j=1; j<=1; j++){
  System.out.print("||");    
  }
 System.out.println();
  }
  
System.out.println("_____||_____");

  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean the last space needs to be a floor? are you not printing a floor on the last print statement?

Comment: the print that i use for the last part of the trunk and the "floor" (aka the underscores) need to be in the array with a for, not just printed.

Comment: you aren't using an array in your code, though.

Comment: if you meant you want to print it using the for loop, you can do this :                ```for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){ if(i == 5 || i == 6){ System.out.print('|'); } else{ System.out.print('_'); } } System.out.println();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//floor
for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * 6; i++) {
    System.out.print(i == 6 ? "||" : "_");
}
```